# Set same alarm for two different times android

Tags: android, android-alarms

I want to set alarm before one minute, two minute and both one and two minute. Actually user will choose one of this value from spinner. Alarm is fired successfully for one minute and two minute before. But for both one and two minute before, it is executing only once and not twice. I have written this code

```
    private void createPendingIntent(String name, int id, String time, String date){

        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), VisitReminderNotificationMessage.class);
        intent.putExtra("Id", id);
        intent.putExtra("Doctor Name", name);
        intent.putExtra("Date", date);
        intent.putExtra("Time", time);

        pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), id, intent, 0);
    }

private void createReminders(long timeInMilliseconds, String remindsBefore){

    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

    long newTimeInMilliseconds;

    if (remindsBefore.equals("1 min")) {
        newTimeInMilliseconds = timeInMilliseconds - 1 * 60 *1000;

        alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, newTimeInMilliseconds, pendingIntent);
    } else if (remindsBefore.equals("2 min")) {
        //Convert 24 Hrs to milliseconds
        newTimeInMilliseconds = timeInMilliseconds - 2* 60 * 1000;

        alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, newTimeInMilliseconds, pendingIntent);
    } else if (remindsBefore.equals("Both 1 and 2 min")){

        //AlarmManager alarmManager1 = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

        long newTimeInMilliseconds1 = timeInMilliseconds - 1 * 60 * 1000;
        long newTimeInMilliseconds2 = timeInMilliseconds - 2* 60 * 1000;

        alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, newTimeInMilliseconds1, pendingIntent);
        alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, newTimeInMilliseconds2, pendingIntent1);
    }
}

And broadcast receiver that I have used to show notification is

    import android.app.NotificationManager;
    import android.app.PendingIntent;
    import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.media.RingtoneManager;
    import android.net.Uri;
    import android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat;

    import com.spirant.epilife.R;
    import com.spirant.epilife.activity.VisitReminderActivity;

    public class VisitReminderNotificationMessage extends BroadcastReceiver{

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

            Intent intent1 = new Intent(context, VisitReminderActivity.class);

            String doctorName = intent.getStringExtra("Doctor Name");
            int notificationId = intent.getIntExtra("Id", 0);
            String date = intent.getStringExtra("Date");
            String time = intent.getStringExtra("Time");

            PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent1, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);

            Uri alarmSound = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_ALARM);
            // Build the notification
            NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
                    .setContentText("Doctor Name: " + doctorName + "\n" + "Date: " + date
                            + "\n" + "Time: " + time)
                    .setContentTitle("Visit your Doctor")
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.app_icon)
                    .setCategory(NotificationCompat.CATEGORY_ALARM)
                    .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                    .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText("Doctor Name: " + doctorName + "\n" + "Date: " + date
                            + "\n" + "Time: " + time))
                    .setSound(alarmSound)
                    .setAutoCancel(true);

            NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

            // Pass the notification to the notification manager
            mNotificationManager.notify(notificationId, notificationBuilder.build());
        }
    }
```

Please someone help..

Answer (score 0):

you have to call again set alarmManager inside VisitReminderNotificationMessage's onReceiver after sending notification

```
 AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
     alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, newTimeInMilliseconds1, pendingIntent);
```